# Highlight the closing tag of the currently selected opening tag

Tags: visual-studio-code

One thing I'm missing from SublimeText, is it's ability to highlight the currently selected elements closing tag.

For eg,

[image: highlight tag]

Because my cursor is in a `div`, it highlights every occurrence of the word `div` when it would be so much more useful, to rather highlight the *closing* div only.

Is this possible?

Comment: Hope this helps, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vincaslt.highlight-matching-tag

Comment: There is an extension that might help: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vincaslt.highlight-matching-tag

Comment: thanks to you both. plugin is quite ugly though :P tried it, customized it, still hated it, so deleted it.

i think my questino perhaps should have been rephrased to ask WHY every occurrence of a word is being highlighted, when the default behavior of Code (AFAIK) is to highlight the closing bracket.

considering i have `"editor.occurrencesHighlight": false,`, it really shouldn't be doing this?

Comment: @Mark could you solve the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem as OP, and finally found the solution!!

As it turns out, the same issue was only occurring to me **when editing .PHP files.**

Placing my cursor on any tag will trigger auto highlighting for any occurring tags that matched. See image below:

[image]

To turn this behaviour off, add this into your settings.json in VS code:

```
"editor.occurrencesHighlight": false,
```

To target specific languages, add this instead:

```
 "[php]": {
    "editor.occurrencesHighlight": true,
 }
```

Result:

[image]

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Late as hell, but VSCode now supports matching tag highlighting by default, without the need for any extension, as you can see in the following example.

[image: Syntax highlighting]

Answer (score 0):

VSCode will automatically highlight the closing tag of the currently selected opening tag for HTML Files. However, if you're working with .PHP Files then I will suggest you install the PHP Intelephense Extension.

Hope this helps.